# Compiling Nginx on Alpine Linux 3.11

Tags: nginx, compilation, alpine-linux, aio

I am trying to compile Nginx with the below config options, and it keeps failing with the error:

```
checking for kqueue AIO support ... not found
checking for Linux AIO support ... not found
checking for Linux AIO support (SYS_eventfd) ... not found

./configure: no supported file AIO was found

Currently file AIO is supported on FreeBSD 4.3+ and Linux 2.6.22+ only
```

Here's my configure options.  They are the exact same ones I get from running `nginx -V` after installing the nginx Alpine package using `apk add`:

```
--prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/run/nginx/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/nginx/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --with-perl_modules_path=/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-threads --with-file-aio --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_geoip_module=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/njs-0.3.5/nginx --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/ngx_devel_kit-0.3.0 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/ngx_cache_purge-2.5 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/echo-nginx-module-0.61 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/ngx-fancyindex-0.4.3 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/headers-more-nginx-module-0.33 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/lua-nginx-module-0.10.15 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/lua-upstream-nginx-module-0.07 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/nchan-1.2.5 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/nginx-http-shibboleth-2.0.1 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/redis2-nginx-module-0.15 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/set-misc-nginx-module-0.32 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/nginx-upload-progress-module-0.9.2 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/nginx-upstream-fair-0.1.3 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/nginx-rtmp-module-1.2.1 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/nginx-vod-module-1.24 --add-dynamic-module=/home/buildozer/aports/main/nginx/src/ngx_http_geoip2_module-3.2
```

Comment: I'm just curious: why do you compile it yourself?

Comment: I am compiling in 3rd-party modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      Error: 

      ./configure: no supported file AIO was found
       Currently file AIO is supported on FreeBSD 4.3+ and Linux 2.6.22+ only
 Module --with-file-aio,  requires a package: "linux-headers"

      ./configure: error: the HTTP rewrite module requires the PCRE library.
      You can either disable the module by using --without-http_rewrite_module
      option, or install the PCRE library into the system, or build the PCRE library
      statically from the source with nginx by using --with-pcre=<path> option.
requires a package: "pcre-dev" 

      ./configure: error: SSL modules require the OpenSSL library.
      You can either do not enable the modules, or install the OpenSSL library
      into the system, or build the OpenSSL library statically from the source
      with nginx by using --with-openssl=<path> option.
requires a package: "openssl-dev"
```

That's all I needed:  `apk --update add gcc make g++ zlib-dev linux-headers pcre-dev openssl-dev`

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer.  You have to install linux-headers first.